# Why is my JavaFX application startup so slow?

Tags: java, javafx-2, startup

My JavaFX applications always start much slower than Swing applications. Much slower than what is acceptable for a little application.

Is this 'normal' or do I have to make changes somewhere?

EDIT: I heard about some proxy issues that may affect the startup time of JavaFX apps, but I'm not sure how to debug this.

Comment: This is not normal, I am surprised at how instantly my heavy WebView pops out after compilation.

Comment: What resources are you loading, can you provide an example demonstrating your problem?

Comment: @MadProgrammer does not matter the amount of resources. If I try to run a simple Hello World app the startup is slow too.

Comment: Have you tried `-Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true` (see section 13.3.1 of [Deploying JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/troubleshooting.htm))

Comment: Yeah, testing with -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true the app starts much faster. Do I have to create a .bat file to pass that parameter? I dont want a bat file.

Comment: You can put it into the MANIFEST.MF - if you use the packager then there's an option to add the correct header

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on your comments I found that the slowness problem is caused by [autoproxy configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/troubleshooting.htm#A1215576).

[NetBeans 7.4](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) has an option that solves this problem. That is a new option. I think it is not present on NetBeans 7.3.

[image: NetBeans 7.4]

Checking the generated jar, the option `JavaFX-Feature-Proxy: None` is added to the MANIFEST.MF

---

```
* Run the same application from the command line as
  java -jar MyApp.jar

* This way you can see actual exceptions and trace messages (if any).

* Pass "-Djavafx.verbose=true" to enable verbose output from the embedded launcher.

* If your application starts slow, then it could be due to network configuration. 
Try disabling the autoproxy configuration by passing "-Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true" to see if it helps.
```